# Trying to notify a thread that an object has been created using Exchanger results in both threads locked

Tags: java, multithreading

The original idea was to notify another thread when an object is created so that it can use it and I've decided to use an Exchanger to do so by directly sending the object. One thread passes the said object and the receiver sends `null`, but both threads end up locked.

This is the simplified version of my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Exchanger;

public class Intercambiador {
    private Exchanger<Carta> ex = new Exchanger<>();

    public void intercambiar1(){
        while(true){
            Carta c = new Carta((int)(Math.random()*10));
            System.out.println("intercambiador 1 creates the object " + c.getNum());
            try {
               ex.exchange(c);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("intercambiador 1 sleeps");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void intercambiar2(){
        while(true) {
            Carta c = new Carta(-1);
            System.out.println("intercambiador 2 wants to receive an object");
            try {
                c = ex.exchange(null);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("intercambiador 2 receives the object " + c.getNum());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where one thread executes the method `intercambiar1()` and the other executes `intercambiar2()`.
The class `Carta` only contains a number (generated randomly because it doesn't matter), constructor, getter and setter.

The main class that creates the threads looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Intercambiador i1 = new Intercambiador();
        Intercambiador i2 = new Intercambiador();

        new Thread(()->i1.intercambiar1()).start();
        new Thread(()->i2.intercambiar2()).start();
    }
}
```

And the output that this code generates is the following:

```
intercambiador 2 wants to receive an object
intercambiador 1 creates the object 2
```

The program is still running so I assume both threads have locked. Is there anything wrong with how I'm approaching this?

I've also tried to use `wait()` and `notify()`, like so:

```
public class Intercambiador {
    private final Object lock = new Object();


    private void send(Carta c){
        synchronized (lock){
            Main.queue.offer(c);
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    private Carta receive(){
        synchronized (lock){
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return Main.queue.peek();
    }

    public void intercambiar1(){
        while(true){
            Carta c = new Carta((int)(Math.random()*10));
            System.out.println("intercambiador 1 creates the object " + c.getNum());
            send(c);
            System.out.println("intercambiador 1 has sent an object");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void intercambiar2(){
        while(true) {
            Carta c = new Carta(-1);
            System.out.println("intercambiador 2 wants to receive an object");
            c = receive();
            System.out.println("intercambiador 2 recibe la carta " + c.getNum());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Main` class now has a `public static BlockingQueue<Carta> queue`, which is where the object is added when created so that the other thread can access it.

And the output looks like this:

```
intercambiador 2 wants to receive an object
intercambiador 1 creates the object 4
intercambiador 1 has sent an object
intercambiador 1 creates the object 0
intercambiador 1 has sent an object
intercambiador 1 creates the object 5
intercambiador 1 has sent an object
intercambiador 1 creates the object 7
intercambiador 1 has sent an object
```

The execution doesn't stop so I assume somehow the `notify()` function isn't notifying propperly, because the thread that executes `wait()` remains blocked. I use `notify()` rather than `notifyAll()` because the idea is that it wakes up only one thread, not all of the ones that have executed `wait()` on the same object (this is mandatory).

Also I have to point out that I have explicitly created the object `lock` because, as I said, this is a simplification of the bigger problem, where I have to do this 3 times and each one between different threads. There will also be multiple threads executing `intercambiar1()` and `intercambiar2()` in the future.

The main point of this problem is that one thread has to **notify** the other when the object is created. It looks like the classical producer-consumer problem, but I can't seem to be able to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest getting a stack dump and analyzing the various threads' state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nah, you have two `Intercambiador` objects, working with their own `Exchanger`s, so they never meet.

Short fix for testing would be

Having a single one as static:

```
static private Exchanger<Carta> ex = new Exchanger<>();
```

Or creating a single object:

```
Intercambiador i = new Intercambiador();
//Intercambiador i2 = new Intercambiador();

new Thread(()->i.intercambiar1()).start();
new Thread(()->i.intercambiar2()).start();
```

Long fix would be creating a single `Exchanger` outside, and passing it as argument, something like

```
Exchanger<Carta> exchanger = new Exchanger<>();
Intercambiador i1 = new Intercambiador(exchanger);
Intercambiador i2 = new Intercambiador(exchanger);

new Thread(()->i1.intercambiar1()).start();
new Thread(()->i2.intercambiar2()).start();
```

(and of course creating the necessary constructor for `Intercambiador`)

Comment: Long fix worked like charm on the simplified version.

Comment: The issue with `wait`/`notify` is the same, btw. Also note that `BlockingQueue`s do not need extra magics anyway, they can do the blocking, that is where the name comes from.

Comment: I noticed the `wait/notify` problem was the same right after your first answer and it makes a lot of sense. It worked like charm on the "big problem" too! Thanks!